# Não consigo abrir o Jupyter Notebook nem o Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, instalador, anaconda

Realizei a instalação do Anaconda Python corretamente, mas quando tento abrir o Jupyter Notebook pelo console digitando "Jupyter Notebook" aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 60, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado.
(base) PS C:\Users\alex>
```

Também não consegui abrir o Anaconda Navigator.

Não compreendi o motivo desse erro ter acontecido, uma vez que segui corretamente o passo a passo da instalação do Anaconda Python. Alguém pode me explicar porque não consigo abrir o Jupyter Notebook nem o Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Boa tarde, tente [essa correção](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240362/18849455)

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado.